# Is there a way I can make it so this button on click alternates between true/false?

Tags: c#, boolean

I'm new to C#, and I'm struggling with allowing a button to repeat a VLC media player sound/video.  I want to make it so on click, it loops it to true, and on another click, it loops it to false.

Here's the code:

```
    private void button22_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        axWindowsMediaPlayer1.settings.setMode("loop", true);

    }
```

Comment: `setMode("loop", !getMode("loop"))`, assuming there is a `getMode`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can do it, declare a `bool` member let’s say `flag` in the class. And set like this `flag = !flag;` inside the button click event and use it.